LXC Unsupported compression during init
I'm trying to find a way to import a lxc image to an airgapped system. So far I'm running tests with alpine to determine if this is possible. So far I did:
My dev-system:
$ lxc-create alpine -t oci -- url docker://alpine
$ lxc image export images:alpine alpine.tar.xz

This imports alpine from docker and produced two files alpine.tar.xz and alpine.tar.xz.root which presumably hold the image blob and metadata. Now to import the image into my target system:
$ lxc image import alpine.tar.xz alpine.tar.xz.root --alias alpine

The import is successful and the alpine image shows up when lxc image list is invoked.
However when I try to start a container with this image I get:
$ lxc init alpine testing
Creating testing
Error: Unsupported compression

I have already verified that xz is indeed available on the target system. Anyone have any Idea where I went wrong?
